# FontAwesome not available as a font-family?

Tags: css, font-face, font-awesome

This is undoubtedly me doing something really dumb, but I can't see it. I'm trying to use FontAwesome as a font-family in my css, but it doesn't seem to be working.

With minimal code, I have:

```
<head>
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: FontAwesome;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Test FontAwesome!
</body>
```

This is showing up as clearly Times New Roman.

The FontAwesome font itself is stored in assets/font/, and font-awesome.css has the following `@font-face` defined:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
    url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Changing the `..` to `assets` gives an obvious error that it can't find the font, so I'm pretty sure the relative pathing is just fine and dandy. If I change it to `font-family: FontAwesome,Arial;`, it uses Arial. Clearly, it can't find FontAwesome and I don't know why.

Any particular reason why I'm not able to change my body font to FontAwesome?

Answer (score 10):

Much better is use this:

```
<head>

<!-- fonts awesome -->

<link href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
```

In your stylesheet use only for example:

```
#post-title a:before {

    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f0c4";

}
```

No less, no more :))))

Comment: You don't want to import all FontAwesome CSS only for its `font-face` rule.

Answer (score 8):

You are listing relative path, sometimes they cause unexpected issues due to spelling errors. I can't count how many times I have messed up the link by actually having a folder called `fonts` instead of `font`.

Try Yovav's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28556064/3616018) (below) to see if that clears the issue up if not, try using absolute paths instead or make sure the links are correct.

If you are struggling with local font-face, you can try a "remote" font-face via cdn (has benefit of maybe being cached already by the browser from other sites)

```
// Swap http for https if required.

@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style : normal;
           src : url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0");
           src : url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0") format("embedded-opentype"),
                 url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0") format("woff2"),
                 url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0") format("woff"),
                 url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0") format("truetype"),
                 url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Make sure both .woff and .woff2 are recognized by the server...

Add this in web.config at the  element:

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Solved my errors, thanks @Yovav. It makes sense as IIS server may prevent some file extensions. Adding this tells IIS to allow these file extensions to execute

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to get this working until I added the word "before" to the style name.  That fixed it for me!

```
.myClass:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f024";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first question that needs to be answered is what web browser are you using. Not all browsers support custom fonts. Some do, but only with extra hacked up CSS/HTML.

I recommend testing it out first in Chrome (it seems to have the best font support).

Answer (score 0):

you are write Wrong: `font-family: FontAwesome;`

Please write like this. `font-family:'FontAwesome';`

I think this will help u, because I had the same problem before one month.

Comment: If a [`font-family` name](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#family-name-value) can be an [identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), quotes aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

FontAwesome characters are icons stored in Unicode's private use area only, so if your text doesn't use these characters you can't see the font.

Try `&#xF00C;`.